# Dump USB Safenet Sentinel UltraPro to DNG file for emulate

Tags: usb, clone, dump, dongle

I need to make a clone for USB safenet Sentinel UltraPro ?

I tried to dump the files with the files from : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dn-3oj0gH9M2OunUCw8H8kq1s2j6zyYg

1st I use the dumper.exe to make the USB BIN file.

2nd I need to make a DNG file using bin2dng.exe

I failed to make the DNG file... It said :

```
Error: can't get dongle ID
Error: Initializing Sentinel SuperPro API
```

Anybody know how to make it into DNG files and run on SENTEMUL2010 64 Bit.exe ?

PS : I use Windows 10 64 bit, and I already enter the restart with "disable device signature enforcement" but still cannt get the DNG file...